# Run Bash script against a Google Compute instance by ssh, from your machine

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run a script that is on my machine on a Google Compute instance. I'd like the script to connect in and do its work, and was surprised to see behavior from below:

```
#!/bin/bash

gcloud compute ssh myinstance

echo "blah" > /tmp/test.txt
```

This script does connect to `myinstance`, but it writes `/tmp/test.txt` on my machine, not the compute instance. The ssh connection remains when the script ends, my terminal is connected.

I had expected it to connect, write the file to the compute instance, and disconnect from ssh. How do I maintain scripts on my machine and run then against various compute instances easily, by ssh? The main use case is going from Mac to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you want to run on the remote server should be as an argument to `ssh`:

```
gcloud compute ssh myinstance 'echo "blah" > /tmp/test.txt'
```

Comment: is there a way to run my entire script as ssh on that server?

Comment: The best way is to copy the script there and then run it.

Answer (score 4):

```
WORK_PROJECTS_PATH="$HOME/path"

BACKEND_SCRIPT_NAME="redeploy_backend.sh"
LOCAL_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH="$WORK_PROJECTS_PATH/myproject/scripts/deploy/$BACKEND_SCRIPT_NAME"
REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_TEMP_PATH="/tmp/$BACKEND_SCRIPT_NAME"
REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH="/home/path/$BACKEND_SCRIPT_NAME"

GCP_INSTANCE="myproject-staging"

gcloud config set project myproject_name
# move current version of script over each time to ensure it's up to date
gcloud compute ssh $GCP_INSTANCE --command="sudo rm -f $REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH"
# sending to temp path allows you to skip entering the compute instance password
gcloud compute copy-files $LOCAL_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH $GCP_INSTANCE:$REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_TEMP_PATH

gcloud compute ssh $GCP_INSTANCE --command="sudo mv $REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_TEMP_PATH $REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH"
gcloud compute ssh $GCP_INSTANCE --command="sudo chmod +x $REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH"
# run the script on the server from your machine
gcloud compute ssh $GCP_INSTANCE --command="$REMOTE_BACKEND_SCRIPT_PATH"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by first copying the script to the instance and then running it remotely (set the env vars according to your environment):

```bash
PROJECT="<your GCP project ID>"
ZONE="<your compute zone>"
LOCAL_SCRIPT="/example/local/path/to/script.sh"
REMOTE_SCRIPT="/tmp/script.sh"
INSTANCE_NAME="some-instance"

chmod +x "${LOCAL_SCRIPT}"

gcloud compute scp \
    --project "${PROJECT}" \
    --zone "${ZONE}" \
    "${LOCAL_SCRIPT}" "${INSTANCE_NAME}:${REMOTE_SCRIPT}"

gcloud compute ssh \
    --project "${PROJECT}" \
    --zone "${ZONE}" \
    "${INSTANCE_NAME}" -- "${REMOTE_SCRIPT}"
```

Comment: bash: /tmp/script.sh: Permission denied, any idea?

Comment: @Mahboob `chmod +x "${LOCAL_SCRIPT}"` before the gcloud commands may fix it